# EntryPointNotFoundException when attempting to use TransformXml in custom build activity

Tags: tfsbuild, web-config-transform

In the process of setting up TFS 2013 to build and deploy sites and services to dev and test systems, I came across [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7325379/595473) for creating a custom build activity to transform Web.config files.  I've added it to a build process template and TFS is calling it during its build/deploy process, though when transformation.Execute() is called, I receive

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll
>
> Additional information: Entry point was not found.

I created a quick console app to call the custom activity directly and I get the same exception thrown on my local machine as well.

For reference, here's the custom build activity from the answer I linked above

```
/// <summary>
/// Transforms configuration files using TransformXml
/// </summary>
[BuildActivity(HostEnvironmentOption.All)]
public sealed class WebConfigTransform : CodeActivity
{
    #region Public Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// The binaries folder
    /// </summary>
    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<string> BinariesLocation { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Overrides of CodeActivity

    /// <summary>
    /// When implemented in a derived class, performs the execution of the activity.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The execution context under which the activity executes.</param>
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        var binariesFolder = context.GetValue(BinariesLocation);

        foreach (var sourceFolder in Directory.GetDirectories(Path.Combine(binariesFolder, "_PublishedWebsites")))
        {
            var sourceFile = Path.Combine(sourceFolder, "Web.config");
            if (File.Exists(sourceFile))
            {
                var filesToTransform = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder, "Web.*.config");


                foreach (var fileToTransform in filesToTransform)
                {

                    var tempSourceFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
                    var tempTransformFile = Path.GetTempFileName();

                    File.Copy(sourceFile, tempSourceFile, true);
                    File.Copy(fileToTransform, tempTransformFile, true);

                    var transformation = new TransformXml
                    {
                        BuildEngine = new BuildEngineStub(),
                        Source = tempSourceFile,
                        Transform = tempTransformFile,
                        Destination = fileToTransform
                    };

                    transformation.Execute();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}


public class BuildEngineStub : IBuildEngine
{
    #region IBuildEngine Members

    public bool BuildProjectFile(string projectFileName, string[] targetNames,
                                 IDictionary globalProperties,
                                 IDictionary targetOutputs)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int ColumnNumberOfTaskNode
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }

    public bool ContinueOnError
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public int LineNumberOfTaskNode
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }

    public string ProjectFileOfTaskNode
    {
        get { return ""; }
    }

    public void LogCustomEvent(CustomBuildEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Custom: {0}", e.Message);
    }

    public void LogErrorEvent(BuildErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
    }

    public void LogMessageEvent(BuildMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", e.Message);
    }

    public void LogWarningEvent(BuildWarningEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Warning: {0}", e.Message);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I had references to the incorrect versions of the dlls I needed; it compiled just fine but wouldn't run properly.

Rather than search through C:\ to find the dlls necessary as suggested on another site, I found the four Microsoft assemblies I needed in Reference Manager > Assemblies > Framework

> Microsoft.Build.Framework
>
> Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0
>
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client
>
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow

This ended up fixing my problem, and the config file is now being transformed as needed